# How to get value without subqueries (on SQL-Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have the following table on SQL Server:

```
ID   Num
 1     A
 2     B
 2     B
 3     C
 3     C
 4     C
```

(`Num` is a numeric column - A, B, and C are standins for numeric values, for the purpose of this question)

How to get the value of `A+B+C+C` without using subqueries and CTE?

**A** - for 1, **B** - for 2, **C** - for 3, **C** - for 4.

The answer seems to `sum(distinct Num)`, but distinct is by ID field!

### Demo table:

```
create table test (ID int, Num int);
insert into test values (1, 10);
insert into test values (2, 100);
insert into test values (2, 100);
insert into test values (3, 1000);
insert into test values (3, 1000);
insert into test values (4, 1000);
```

The correct answer is 10+100+1000+1000 = 2110.

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous. What number would you expect as an answer given your data?

Comment: ID isn't unique in your table?

Comment: Absolutelly real. And very intersting and hard question!

Comment: Please create an example here http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```
select cast(sum(distinct Num + cast(0.00001 as number(38,19))/ID) as number(18,2))
```

Comment: +1 because that's sneaky, but it could I think it could fail in extreme (unrealistic) circumstances (you'd need to be adding an awful lot of numbers before the fractional parts eventually go over 1 though). You could do `Select Cast(Sum(Distinct Num + Cast(0.1 as numeric(38,19))/Id) -
Sum(Distinct Cast(0.1 as Numeric(38,19))/Id) As Numeric(18, 2))` to get around that.

Answer (score 2):

A random guess, using CTE to avoid the pointless subquery restriction:

```
With X as (Select Distinct Id, No From Test)

Select
  Sum(No) 
From X
```

Or using a derived table (which works in SQL 2000):

```
Select
  Sum(No)
From (
  Select Distinct
    Id,
    No
  From
    Test
) a;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77a6e/6

Comment: I was about to add the "normal" subselect version to your answer, but you were faster. :) Good job, +1.

Comment: -1 because both solutions uses either Subqueries OR CTE wich the OP said must not be used.

Comment: @Lostdreamer Sub queries and derived tables are different things.

Comment: Fundamentally a Sub query is a query nested within in another query. 
Derived table or whatever, it's still a query nested within another query. Have a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: "A subquery can be used anywhere an expression is allowed". Whereas derived tables can be used anywhere a table source is allowed.

Comment: I can't add `distinct` and `select sum(Num)` as parent query to my query with fixed structure and fixed rows count.

Comment: I don't say you can't use a subquery the way you did it, it's just that the original question specified that it should not be used (for whatever reason)